# WPF Prism Inject same viewmodel instance into two views

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

So I have two separate views in a WPF Prism app. How can I inject the same *instance* of a `ViewModel` into both the views via Dependency Injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume you are using Unity as you mentioned DI directly and are not saying "Import" or similar)

Hi,

You will have to register the ViewModel as a singleton (using a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager) in the container and have it injected as usual. This ensures that you will get the same instance whenever you request for it.
A valid approach in this scenario might be to use a named registration in case you want to get the same VM injected elsewhere, but you don't need the same instance.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28PandP.20%29.aspx#runtime_register_lifemgr) explains how to do this.

Comment: Many thanks. Actually the ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager was what I really needed. You sent me in the right direction.

Comment: Some DI frameworks will let you make named instances. You could use those if a singleton is not what you want.